# How to add border bottom between div in small device without affecting in large device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In large Device border right should be display and in small device border bottom should be display without affecting in large device and some spacing between div in small Device
[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your question, following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It doesn´t have sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="box">
    ...
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="box">
    ...
    </div>
</div>

<style>
/*Desktop*/
.box{ border-right:#000 solid 1px;}

/*Small Screen - below 768 resolution device*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .box{border-right:none; border-bottom:#000 solid 1px; margin-bottom:20px;}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add media query to small device

```html
  @media only screen and (max-width: 300px)
 {
 your div name 
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: thick dotted #ff0000;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="box">
    ...
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="box">
    ...
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.box{ border-right:#000 solid 1px;}

/*Small Screen - below 768 resolution device*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){.box{border-right:none; border-bottom:#000 solid 1px; margin-bottom:20px;}}
</style>
```